# Generic-Class with java.nio.Buffer

Tags: java, generics, buffer

An API-call is defined for different Buffer-classes:

```
apicall(ByteBuffer buffer);
apicall(FloatBuffer buffer);
apicall(IntBuffer buffer);
apicall(LongBuffer buffer);
apicall(DoubleBuffer buffer);
```

I need to write some classes working with that, but instead of writing five classes I want to use a generic class.

```
MyClass<T extends Buffer> ...
```

The Problem with that is, that apicall() is not defined for every Buffer, i.e. not for CharBuffer.

```
myMethod(T buffer) {apicall(buffer);}
```

fails. My workaround is something like this:

```
if (buffer instanceof FloatBuffer) {
    apicall((FloatBuffer)buffer);
} else if (buffer instanceof ByteBuffer) {
    apicall((ByteBuffer)buffer);
} else ...
```

I don't feel well with this. My question is, if there is a better way to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you modify Buffer classes, i.e to add method supportFeature() ?

Comment: I have no access to the API sources.

Comment: Nope, there's no better alternative.